# Получить классы у которых конечное название одинаково

Tags: javascript, классы, queryselector

Есть классы, например add_pdd-value, bdd_ogg-value, fff_ooo-value
И таких классов штук 15. Все заканчиваются на value.
Как получить все эти классы, зная, что они заканчиваются на value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let test = [...document.querySelectorAll('[class$="value"]')];

test.forEach((el) => console.log(el.getAttribute('class')));
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="add_pdd-value">add_pdd-value</div>
<div class="bdd_ogg-value">bdd_ogg-value</div>
<div class="something">something</div>
<div class="fff_ooo-value">fff_ooo-value</div>
<div class="something-else">something-else</div>
```

Конечно тут при выводе в консоль пока не учитывается то, что в элементе могут быть еще и другие классы. Но найти элементы можно по `[class$="value"]`

В *CSS* селектор `[attribute$="value"]` как раз ищет элементы, у которых указанный атрибут заканчивается на какое-то значение

Comment: Спасибо большое. Облазил весь гугл и совсем забыл, что в emmet пишу короткую запись последовательности через $

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```js
arr = [];

document.querySelectorAll("*").forEach((elem) => 
    elem.classList.forEach((c) => {
        if (c && c.length > 0 && c.match(/value/gi)) {
             // здесь и сейчас в elem лежит результат
             document.getElementById("result").appendChild(elem)
             // ссылки на результат можно сохранять в массив, например
             arr.push(elem);
        } 
    })
);

//console.log(arr);
```

```html
<div class="abc-value">hello</div>
    <p class="underclass-value">underClass</p>
    <p class="underclass-vallllue">underClass NOT CORRECT</p>
<div class="stillone-value with any classes">Correct with any classes</div>

<div id="result">
    <h5>result:</h5>
</div>
```

Должно работать с любым видом селекторов, вложенными элементами и с другими классами.

Comment: `<p class="value-not-correct">underClass</p>`